# Inserting Sales Price of Parent Item in Bill of Materials without repetition

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having Bill of material table in which I wish to insert Sales Price (Only once in first line only) on the basis of `ParentItemCode`.

The price of Parent Item `X` is 1735 and `Y` is 3000.

Following is the data:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    LineNum INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,ParentPnxCode VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
    ,ChildPnxCode VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
    ,Unit VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    10000
    ,'X'
    ,'x1'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    20000
    ,'X'
    ,'x2'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    30000
    ,'X'
    ,'x3'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    40000
    ,'X'
    ,'x4'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    50000
    ,'X'
    ,'x5'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    60000
    ,'X'
    ,'x6'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    70000
    ,'X'
    ,'x7'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    5000
    ,'Y'
    ,'y1'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    7500
    ,'Y'
    ,'y2'
    ,'PCS'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    LineNum
    ,ParentPnxCode
    ,ChildPnxCode
    ,Unit
    )
VALUES (
    8750
    ,'Y'
    ,'y2'
    ,'PCS'
    );
```

Following is the desired output:

```
+---------+---------------+--------------+------+-------------------+
| LineNum | ParentPnxCode | ChildPnxCode | Unit | Old Selling Price |
+---------+---------------+--------------+------+-------------------+
|   10000 | X             | x1           | PCS  |              1735 |
|   20000 | X             | x2           | PCS  |                 0 |
|   30000 | X             | x3           | PCS  |                 0 |
|   40000 | X             | x4           | PCS  |                 0 |
|   50000 | X             | x5           | PCS  |                 0 |
|   60000 | X             | x6           | PCS  |                 0 |
|   70000 | X             | x7           | PCS  |                 0 |
|    5000 | Y             | y1           | PCS  |              3000 |
|    7500 | Y             | y2           | PCS  |                 0 |
|    8750 | Y             | y2           | PCS  |                 0 |
+---------+---------------+--------------+------+-------------------+
```

Could u please help me achieving the above output? Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question [to other forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/500da1e6-f34c-42ab-aa9d-9689c7e58eca/inserting-sales-price-of-parent-item-in-bill-of-materials-without-repetition?forum=transactsql) so that everyone can waste time chasing the same information.

Comment: From where 1735 and 3000 are coming from?

Answer (score 1):

This query should give you the result that you want. It relies on `ROW_NUMBER()` to find out if the current record is the first in the group, and accordingly displays the expected value:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentPnxCode ORDER BY LineNum) = 1
        THEN CASE ParentPnxCode
            WHEN 'X' THEN 1735
            WHEN 'Y' THEN 3000
        END
        ELSE 0
    END OldSellingPrice
FROM mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2cd122361d410f98d7b3b47f2cb4abc)**:

```
LineNum | ParentPnxCode | ChildPnxCode | Unit | OldSellingPrice
------: | :------------ | :----------- | :--- | --------------:
  10000 | X             | x1           | PCS  |            1735
  20000 | X             | x2           | PCS  |               0
  30000 | X             | x3           | PCS  |               0
  40000 | X             | x4           | PCS  |               0
  50000 | X             | x5           | PCS  |               0
  60000 | X             | x6           | PCS  |               0
  70000 | X             | x7           | PCS  |               0
   5000 | Y             | y1           | PCS  |            3000
   7500 | Y             | y2           | PCS  |               0
   8750 | Y             | y2           | PCS  |               0
```

---

If you are looking to actually create a new column in the table to store that information, you could go (`ROW_NUMBER()` is not allowed in `SET` clause I switched to a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition):

```
ALTER table mytable ADD OldSellingPrice int;
UPDATE t
SET t.OldSellingPrice = 
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mytable t1 WHERE t.ParentPnxCode = t1.ParentPnxCode AND t1.LineNum < t.LineNum)
        THEN CASE ParentPnxCode
            WHEN 'X' THEN 1735
            WHEN 'Y' THEN 3000
        END
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e530d3e252ba395ec21e813305582a41)**

Answer (score 0):

IF the price of Parent Item stored in the master table.

```
SELECT LineNum, ParentPnxCode, ChildPnxCode, Unit, 
Old_Selling_Price = IIF((LAG(ParentPnx_Price) OVER(PARTITION BY mytable.ParentPnxCode ORDER BY mytable.ParentPnxCode) IS NULL),ParentPnx_Price,0)
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN ParentPnx_Master ON mytable.ParentPnxCode = ParentPnx_Master.ParentPnxCode
ORDER BY mytable.ParentPnxCode
```